# Give editors access to particular plugin - turn "admin.php" into "edit.php"

Tags: plugins, dashboard, editor, user-access

I'm using the [Business Opening Hours](https://wordpress.org/plugins/business-opening-hours/) plugin. I made it appear in the sidebar using the [Client Dash](https://wordpress.org/plugins/client-dash/) plugin, but when the *Editor* clicks it, they cannot access it, only the *Admins*, how can I change that?

I found some code snippets in the plugin, can I change something here?

```
if( is_admin() )
$bizohours_settings_page = new BizoHoursSettingPage();

public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'bizohours_plugin_page' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'bizohours_page_init' ) );
    }

/**
 * Add plugin page
 */
public function bizohours_plugin_page()
{
    // This page will be in "Dashboard Menu"
    add_menu_page(
        __('Settings Admin', 'bizo-hours'), 
        __('Öffnungszeiten', 'bizo-hours'), 
        'manage_options', 
        'bizohours-setting-admin', 
        array( $this, 'bizohours_admin_page' ),
        plugins_url( 'images/icon.png',__FILE__)
    );
}
```

Comment: I'd be careful when making custom changes to the plugin, especially when it updates, all of your custom tweaks will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, it's not the best practice to edit the plugin's source codes because this will be overwritten if you were to get the latest update from the author.

Nonetheless, to allow the [Business Opening Hours](https://wordpress.org/plugins/business-opening-hours/) plugin to show for your *Editors* open `/business-opening-hours/bizo-hours.php` and tweak the following lines. At the time of this writing, the current version for this plugin is v1.0.7:

#### Line 614-616

Replace

```
/**** Instantiate Class ****/
if( is_admin() )
    $bizohours_settings_page = new BizoHoursSettingPage();
```

With

```
/**** Instantiate Class ****/
$bizohours_settings_page = new BizoHoursSettingPage();
```

#### Lines 26-40

Replace

```
/**
 * Add plugin page
 */
public function bizohours_plugin_page()
{
    // This page will be in "Dashboard Menu"
    add_menu_page(
        __('Settings Admin', 'bizo-hours'), 
        __('Business Hours', 'bizo-hours'), 
        'manage_options', 
        'bizohours-setting-admin', 
        array( $this, 'bizohours_admin_page' ),
        plugins_url( 'images/icon.png',__FILE__)
    );
}
```

With

```
/**
 * Add plugin page
 */
public function bizohours_plugin_page()
{
    // This page will be in "Dashboard Menu"
    add_menu_page(
        __('Settings Admin', 'bizo-hours'), 
        __('Business Hours', 'bizo-hours'), 
        'edit_others_pages', 
        'bizohours-setting-admin', 
        array( $this, 'bizohours_admin_page' ),
        plugins_url( 'images/icon.png',__FILE__)
    );
}
```